# Spider plant in my balcony and window

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, indoors

[image]Leaves are turning yellow very fast. I removed the old ones and now again other leaves are turning yellow.It’s rainy season in my city. I water the plant in 3-4 days. Even the soil is moist. And the plant receives indirect light. [image]

Comment: Not a snake plant, but a spider plant. Maybe. They like water and sun. Yellow leaves mean a root problem - lift and inspect them.

Comment: Hi NIKITA, welcome to the site.  That is definitely a spider plant, not a snake plant, so I have edited your title to match.  Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @YosefBaskin the one I have in work is turning yellow; its root problem is that's they've filled the pot and pushed out much of the soil! I'm going to trying feeding it a little. I know they can survive long term with no soil because I grew one in water for several years.

Answer (score 1):

I keep a whole bunch of spider plants indoors and water them weekly.  If your plant is living outdoors in the rainy season and you are watering it twice a week (did I understand you correctly?), that could be too much water.  The constant moisture can damage the roots.

If it is suffering from over watering, repot the plant and take the opportunity to remove any rotting roots and dying leaves.  Going forward, be a little more reserved with adding water to the plant.

Comment: With spider plants you can water when the leaves lose their sheen and become dull, with no ill effects. That's a convenient way to give them just enough.